# Set GIF as background of text in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gif

[image: Text with GIF as background]

We can achieve the above styling on the website(using CSS) by setting a GIF as background to text. Is it possible to achieve a similar thing in react native?

Comment: I don't think what you are looking for is possible with gif images.

A better approach is to:
 1. Create this animation in `After Effects`.
 2. Export and use them using  https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native